# how to set css for div and table

Tags: css

I have created a table, with multiple columns.

I would like the first column (with the description of the rows content) to remain static, and have the others scroll much like the 'Freeze' function in excel so the headers can be seen constantly however the actual data and be scrolled. In this case horizontal.

Comment: put some code to investigate further.

Comment: Please try to phrase it right. I have no clue what you mean. Can you please show also what you have tried?

Comment: It wasn't that hard to understand people.

Answer (score 0):

This will need be achieved with Javascript.

You can freeze the first column of the table using code found on a demo at:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/freeze-pane-functionality

and find it in use at:

http://www.disconova.com/open_source/files/freezepanes.htm